# How can I request to open an URL without opening the webbrowser?

Tags: javascript, android

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        setContentView(mScannerView);
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        mScannerView.startCamera();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mScannerView.stopCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(final Result result) {
        //Do anything with result here :D
        Log.w("handleResult", result.getText());
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Scan result");
        builder.setMessage(result.getText());
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();


        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(result.getText().toString()));
        startActivity(browserIntent);

            mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
    }

}
```

I want to directly open the URL once scanning is done and then reopen the camera. Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Try and create your own activity to handle request to open URL in your WebView.

Comment: what do you mean with "directly open the URL"? Do you want to show the website, or do you want to fetch some data?

Comment: What do you mean by "open"? Are you trying to present the content of the URL visually to the user of your app? Or are you trying to download data from this URL to use in your app?

Comment: The url that I want to open is a google form response link. I want it to run in the background once it scans the QR code. I don't want to show it my users in the app.

Answer (score 0):

Try and create your own activity to handle request to open URL .

When I started learning about android and its intents I found it very confusing. But category BROWSABLE in the Manifest does the following.

The target activity can be safely invoked by the browser to display data referenced by a link — for example, an image or an e-mail message.

Read more on: [http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

The two other answers opens the standard web browser and goes to the address specified. If you want a custom browser make the second activity like a web view like [this example](https://mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/).

Answer (score 0):

Use a webview load the URL like below:

```
    webView= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); 
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```